# Making a menu appear and disappear by clicking the same icon

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a standard hamburger icon on a phone show a menu when clicked and make the menu disappear when clicked again. What I have does make the menu appear but not disappear when clicked again. This code doesn't seem to be doing it:

Javascript/Jquery:

```
<script>

function show( elem )

{
    var n=$(elem).is(":visible"); 

    if (n==false){

    $('#'+elem).show();
    }

    if (n==true) {
        $('#'+elem).hide();
    }
}
</script>
```

HTML/PHP

```
<table align="center"><tr><td><a href="#" onclick="show('link1')"><img src="images/hamburger.png"></a> </td></tr></table>

<div id="link1" class="dynamic_link" style="display:none">

  <?php

    phoneMenu(); 

    ?>

</div>
```

Comment: `show('link1')` should be `show('#link1')`

Comment: That didn't work but it did put me on the right track, I changed the code to var n=$('#'+elem).is(":visible"); and it works now, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try utilizing [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle)

```js
// added `foodicon` `id` to `img`,
// removed `onclick` from `html`
$("#foodicon").on("click", function() {
  $("#link1").toggle()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<table align="center">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="#">
        <!-- assign `foodicon` `id` to `img` -->
        <img id="foodicon" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/food">
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div id="link1" class="dynamic_link" style="display:none">
  food menu
</div>
```